# How to setup a skin takeover ad with google DFP / Ad Manager

Tags: ads, google-dfp, double-click-advertising, google-ad-manager

im pretty new to Google DFP  / Ad Manager,

I didn't have any problems implementing the standard formats, but I'm having trouble with the Skin takeover format.

**Like this**

[image: sample image]

I searched the net, but I did not find any solution explained in detail. Even in the Google support archives.

Do you know a tutorial or a solution explained clearly and step by step?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

DFP / Ad Manager does not include a generic takeover template. You will need to develop your own template using a user creative template. See [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/1138308?hl=en) for complete details on how you create a creative template from scratch.

Here are a few advices from my experience developping creative templates :

- your template will be generated within an iframe, so make sure your script is able to amend the TOP frame (add an image background to the body for instance).
- do not forget to add the generic Ad Manager macros to count clicks and impressions

With these, you will be able to build your own custom template and make sure your takeovers are working properly on your site / network.